# HTML escaped in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method call in my view like this

```
<%= Navigation.with(params) do |menu| 
              if current_user && current_user.can_verify?
                menu.item("Listings", manage_listings_path())
                menu.item("Listing changes", needing_change_approval_manage_listings_path())
                menu.item("Flagged Items", flagged_manage_listings_path())
                menu.item("Transfers", manage_listing_transfers_path())
                menu.item("Reviews", manage_listing_reviews_path())
              end
              if current_user && current_user.admin?
                menu.item("Log", manage_verifications_path())
                menu.item("Indexer Compensations", manage_compensations_path())
                menu.item("Users", manage_users_path())
              end
            end%>
```

that splits out the below string

```
"<li><a href="/manage/listings" class="active">Listings</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/listings/needing_change_approval">Listing changes</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/listings/flagged">Flagged Items</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/listing_transfers">Transfers</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/listing_reviews">Reviews</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/verifications">Log</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/compensations">Indexer Compensations</a></li> <li><a href="/manage/users">Users</a></li>"
```

I just get this string in my page. I wanted them to be menus nicely styled by CSS. I am just getting the above raw text in my page. How do I convert this string to be treated as HTML by the browser.

Please help

Here is the navigation class

```
class NavigationMenu < ActionView::Base
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def item(title, path, options={})
    @items ||= Array.new
    unless (route = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path,:method => options[:method]|| :get))
      raise "Unrecognised path #{path}, are you sure it's in routes.rb?"
    end

    @items << content_tag(:li, link_to(title,path, :class => (@params[:controller] == route[:controller] && @params[:action] == route[:action])? 'active' : nil))

  end

  def output
    return '' if @items.blank?
    content_tag(:ul, @items.join("\n"), :id => 'navigation')
  end
end

class Navigation
  def self.with(params, &block)
    menu = NavigationMenu.new(params)
    yield menu
    menu.output
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add a call to the `raw` method:

```
<%= raw ... %>
```

This is necessary, because in Rails 3 every string is escaped by default, unless you use the `raw` method.
It's like an inverse of the `h` method in Rails 2, where every string is unescaped by default, unless you use the `h` method.

**Example:**

This code in Rails 2...

```
<%= h "String which must be escaped" %>
<%= "String which must be output raw %>
```

... must be this in Rails 3:

```
<%= "String which must be escaped" %>
<%= raw "String which must be output raw %>
```

(Although an additional call to `h` doesn't do any harm in Rails 3)

Comment: I enclosed the method call into raw()... the string is still not considered as html

Comment: It might be possible that the `Navigation.with` method doesn't really return a string but instead writes it directly into the output. In that case only the original developer of `Navigation` can help.

Comment: Or you going on an adventure into `Navigation`'s internals. Bring a machete.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the Navigation class.. what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to append `.html_safe` to the string - this will stop rails from escaping it when it's time to output text. Probably best to put it in the `item` method that you call repeatedly.

Comment: I have put the navigation class above. please help

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where / how often you need to call it, but fiddle around with `html_safe`. Try change last line of your `Navigation` class to `menu.output.html_safe`. If that doesn't work, change the last line in your `item` method to this: `@items << content_tag().html_safe`. You might need to do the same anywhere a `content_tag` is. Untested- you should figure it out from there though.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an article regarding XSS protection in Rails 3 when upgrading from Rails 2:
http://developer.uservoice.com/entries/upgrading-to-rails-3-printing-escaped-strings

The idea is to hook code to printing HTML so that we can determine when we are actually printing something we don't want to:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TextHelper

      def simple_format_with_double_escape_reporting(*args)
        HtmlDoubleEscapeReporter.assert_sane(simple_format_without_double_escape_reporting(*args))
      end 
      alias_method_chain :simple_format, :double_escape_reporting
    end 

    module TagHelper
      private
      def content_tag_string_with_double_escape_reporting(*args)
        HtmlDoubleEscapeReporter.assert_sane(content_tag_string_without_double_escape_reporting(*args))
      end 
      alias_method_chain :content_tag_string, :double_escape_reporting
    end 
    module UrlHelper
      def link_to_with_double_escape_reporting(*args, &block)
        HtmlDoubleEscapeReporter.assert_sane(link_to_without_double_escape_reporting(*args, &block))
      end 
      alias_method_chain :link_to, :double_escape_reporting
    end 
  end 
end
```

Method HtmlDoubleEscapeReporter.assert_sane can be written, for example, like this:

```
class HtmlDoubleEscapeReporter
  def self.assert_sane(str)
    if (str.match(/&lt;[a-z]/) || str.match(/&amp;(quot|rarr|larr|amp|#)/)) &&
        !str.match(/looks something you do not want to print/
      send_problem_report('#{str}' looks something you do not want to print")
    end
    return str
  end
end
```

Here, 'looks something you do not want to print' is used to prevent the possibility of infinite loops. The line send_problem_report('#{str}' looks something you do not want to print") can be replaced with a call to "debugger" (from ruby-debug gem) so that you are able to check the backtrace and see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: True! I added the main idea of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new class. At last... I got that bug.

```
class NavigationMenu < ActionView::Base
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def item(title, path, options={})
    @items ||= Array.new
    unless (route = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path,:method => options[:method]|| :get))
      raise "Unrecognised path #{path}, are you sure it's in routes.rb?"
    end

    @items << content_tag(:li, link_to(title,path, :class => (@params[:controller] == route[:controller] && @params[:action] == route[:action])? 'active' : nil))

  end

  def output
    @items = @items.join("\n").html_safe
    return '' if @items.blank?
    content_tag(:ul, @items, :id => 'navigation')
  end
end

class Navigation
  def self.with(params, &block)
    menu = NavigationMenu.new(params)
    yield menu
    menu.output
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what the problem was and also accept an answer.