# how to set html tags in text to highstock tooltip by lazy_high_chart gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, highcharts

I work with ruby on rails and use lazy_high_charts_gem to create highstock chart.
I have to set text to the tooltip by sending string with JS function to the highstock api.

I wrote code (as I saw in the gem example):

```
<%require 'lazy_high_charts' %>
 <%= high_stock("my_id", @h) do |c| %>
     <%= "options.tooltip.formatter = function() {return 'This is text and this is <b>bold</b>!'; }" %>
 <%end %>
```

the tooltip text realy change but the html tags (in the example B) are part of the text.

do you know what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because Rails 3 escapes all view strings by default, whereas rails 2 left them raw by default.

The trick here is to get that formatter line rendered raw:

```
<%= raw("options.tooltip.formatter = function() {return 'This is text and this is <b>bold</b>!'; }") %>
```

In the standard rails idiom:

```
<%= raw "options.tooltip.formatter = function() {return 'This is text and this is <b>bold</b>!'; }" %>
```

More good info on Rails HTML escape practices here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906207/1195261